# deleting and editing acrobat layers

Tags: layer, acrobat, bookmarks

I'm making an interactive map in Adobe Acrobat using layers. Imagine a map with property lines and I click a bookmark to see the property highlighted. click a different bookmark, highlight (with a layer) a different property.

I've got about 40 layers, and bookmarks for each property or category of properties so that when you click it, it displays just the associated image layer(s).

The problem is, people keep requesting changes to the map. I can't delete layers in Acrobat (?), and when I add a layer, the new layer appears with every single bookmark already set up.

The only way I've figured out to make this work is to basically redo the entire map every time. I want to access document javascript to show/hide layers based on bookmarks, but I'm not sure that's accessible. I'm open to options, anything that would get around redoing from scratch every time.

Comment: What are you creating the maps in? That'll help me understand how the bookmarks get added.

Comment: If you're talking about Adobe Acrobat Pro, you can actually remove layers. You have to use the preflight plug-in for it and create a fixup to delete the layer you want, but it is possible.

Comment: what is this preflight plugin and fixup? link?

Comment: No separate link - it's part of Adobe Acrobat. If you look for "preflight" under Tools you should find it.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Acrobat does allow you to manipulate layers using JavaScript. The only confusing bit you need to know is that layers aren't called layers, but OCGs.

OCG stands for "Optional Content Group", which is a technically correct and completely bonkers way to name these things. But well.

From the Adobe Acrobat JavaScript SDK (which you can access on the [Adobe DevNet pages for Acrobat](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/documentation.html)):

```js
function TurnOnOCGsForPage(doc, nPage) {

    var ocgArray = doc.getOCGs(nPage);
    for (var i=0; i < ocgArray.length; i++)
       ocgArray[i].state = true;
}
```